# what is the skywalking agent image address about 7.0.0

Tags: kubernetes

I am now using skywalking as my apm, and now I  am configuring the address of my skywalking agent like this:

```
"initContainers": [
                {
                    "name": "init-agent",
                    "image": "apache/skywalking-agent:7.0.0",
                    "command": [
                        "sh",
                        "-c",
                        "set -ex;mkdir -p /skywalking/agent;cp -r /opt/skywalking/agent/* /skywalking/agent;"
                    ],
                    "resources": {},
                    "volumeMounts": [
                        {
                            "name": "agent",
                            "mountPath": "/skywalking/agent"
                        }
                    ],
                    "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
                    "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
                    "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent"
                }
            ],
```

but it tells me this address is not correct. Is skywalking agent having docker image? What is the docker image address to use in kubernetes v1.16.0 cluster? I am searching from internet and only find a skywalking [base image](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/skywalking-base/tags).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I build the side car image by myself:

```
wget https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/skywalking/7.0.0/apache-skywalking-apm-7.0.0.tar.gz && tar -zxvf apache-skywalking-apm-7.0.0.tar.gz
```

this is the docker file:

```
FROM busybox:latest 

ENV LANG=C.UTF-8

RUN set -eux && mkdir -p /usr/skywalking/agent/

ADD apache-skywalking-apm-bin/agent/ /usr/skywalking/agent/

WORKDIR /
```

Answer (score 2):

We (Apache SkyWalking Team) have officially provided the Java agent Docker image here https://github.com/apache/skywalking-docker/tree/master/java-agent#use-this-image-as-sidecar-of-kubernetes-service, its usage can be also found there.

As for this specific question, you can always pass environment variable to override the default configuration, for the OAP backend address, its env var is `SW_AGENT_COLLECTOR_BACKEND_SERVICES` so you can simply pass `SW_AGENT_COLLECTOR_BACKEND_SERVICES=your-oap-address:11800` to point the agent to your real OAP address.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: agent-as-sidecar
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never

  volumes:
    - name: skywalking-agent
      emptyDir: { }

  containers:
    - name: agent-container
      image: apache/skywalking-java-agent:8.4.0-alpine
      volumeMounts:
        - name: skywalking-agent
          mountPath: /agent
      command: [ "/bin/sh" ]
      args: [ "-c", "cp -R /skywalking/agent /agent/" ]

    - name: app-container
      image: springio/gs-spring-boot-docker
      volumeMounts:
        - name: skywalking-agent
          mountPath: /skywalking
      env:
        - name: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
          value: "-javaagent:/skywalking/agent/skywalking-agent.jar"
        - name: SW_AGENT_COLLECTOR_BACKEND_SERVICES
          value: "your-oap-address-accessible-inside-docker" # <<=== THIS
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'll learn more how to provide more useful answers. Thanks, Espresso!